# Searchkick advanced search body clause nullifies where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

If I do an advanced search with searchkick for elasticsearch-rails like so:

```
products = Activity.search body: {query: {bool: {must: [{ range: { min_age: {lte: 5} } }, { range: { max_age: {gte: 3} } } ] } } }, where: { category: "Programs", start_time: '2015-07-22' }
```

... the where clause is not being applied. Is this to be expected? Must I use body to achieve all of my queries? Is there a way to get around this in searchkick?

slow log output:

```
[2015-07-29 21:03:53,369][INFO ][index.search.slowlog.query] [ES Dev] [activities_development_20150729165655530][2] took[21.1ms], took_millis[21], types[], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"min_age":{"lte":5}}},{"range":{"max_age":{"gte":3}}}]}}}], extra_source[],
```

Comment: Which version of searchkick are you using?

Comment: Also can you set the following parameter in your `elasticsearch.xml` file: `index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.info: 1ms` (near the end of the file) so that all queries will get logged into your slow log file. Then paste the query you see.

Comment: Ok then let's see what the slow log shows us...

Comment: Weird, that's not an ES query... Are you looking at a file called `<clustername>_index_search_slowlog.log`?

Comment: i only have an elasticsearch.yml in config/

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, that was a typo and I couldn't edit when I noticed ;) I meant `elasticsearch.yml` of course

Comment: I think you're showing `logging.yml`. Maybe update your question with properly formatted output, it'll be easier to read and less error-prone. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try this:

```
products = Activity.search body: {bool: {must: [{ range: { min_age: {lte: 5} } }, { range: { max_age: {gte: 3} } } ] } }, where: { category: "Programs", start_time: '2015-07-22' }
```

The difference is that the `body` does not contain a `query` field at the first level. I think searchkick makes the assumption that `body` IS the `query` part and it will transform it into a `filtered` query if a `where` clause is present.

Try it out...

Comment: Thanks but got `Searchkick::InvalidQueryError at /search
[400] {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], Parse Failure [No parser for element [bool]]]; }]","status":400}`

Answer (score 0):

```
conditions = { category: "Programs", start_time: '2015-07-22' }

query = Activity.search params[:query], execute: false, where : conditions

query.body[:query] =   {bool: {must: [{ range: { min_age: {lte: 5} } }, { range: { max_age: {gte: 3} } } ] } }

query.body[:size] = 10

query.execute
```