# Fetching results in random order with a :where clause using searchkick and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

This is probably a simple thing, but I can't seem to get my head around it:

I want elasticsearch to return:

```
@random_books   = Book.search("*", where: { status: :published }, body: { query: { function_score: { random_score: { seed: seed }}}}, page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
```

The `results` returned do not honor the `where: {status: :published}` clause. How do I syntax up this query?

Edits: Found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714273/searchkick-advanced-search-body-clause-nullifies-where-clause?rq=1) asking basically the same thing; without a working solution/answer of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's the solution:

```
seed = Time.zone.now.to_i

@random_books   = Book
                    .search("*",
                      body: {
                        query: {
                          function_score: {
                            query: {
                              match: { status: :published }
                              },
                            random_score: {
                              seed: seed
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      page: params[:random],
                      per_page: 12)
```

Searchkick will [ignore the `options`](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#advanced-search) (like `where:` clause) if we pass `body` to elasticsearch. So we `match` the `query` inside of `function_score` as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/0-90-4-released).

Easy-peasy.

Answer (score 0):

Please, replace your where clause like this:

> where: { 'status IN(?)', ['published'] }

Comment: I tried this already. Errors out to 500, without anything in logs/trace. :-(

Comment: Is `status` enum? if yes then you also can write like `status.published?` it will return true or false.

Comment: Just an ordinary model attribute of book with validation like so: `validates :status, inclusion: { in: %w(draft published trash)… }`.

Comment: great! try this one

`where('status IN(?)', 'published')`

Comment: Noope. Tried `where('status IN(?)', 'published')` and `where: { 'status IN(?)', 'published' }` but both failed. Tried `where: { 'status IN(?)': "published" }` which gives the same result -- as in, the results ignore the `where: :published` clause.

Comment: please try this one also,
`where: { 'status IN(?)', ['published'] }`

Comment: Did not work… it's probably the `body: { query: { function_score: { random_score: { seed: seed }}}}` object that has to carry this `where: :published` clause to `elasticsearch`. I'll try this with a fresh mind tomorrow. Thank you sparing your time on this @asmita kalena.